# ¿Como puedo guardar los click que da el usuario?

Tags: javascript

Mi codigo es un juego de memoria asi que , el usuario debera repetir dichos colores que salen en 5 botones y  no se como hacer , para guardar esos clicks que de el usuario sobre los botones , necesito ayuda.

Comment: En referencia  a que cada vez que el usuario de un click sobre los 5 botones que piensa que salieron los colores , debo guardar esos clicks y compararlos con la secuencia.... pero , no se como:c

Comment: Te recomiendo repasar sobre los [listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), puedes hacer el llamado a una función cuando se hace clic a un elemento.

Comment: Hola  user326303, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 1):

```
const secuencia = ['rojo','verde','azul']
let colorClicks = [];


//Se obtiene todos los botones para interactuar en el
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-button');

//se recorre todos los botones
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  //se agrega el evento para hacer click
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //agrega el valor del boton al array
    colorClicks.push(button.value);
    //si la cantidad en la secuencia es la misma que la del usuario llama la logica de la comprobacion
    if( secuencia.length >= useClicks.length) {
     comprobarColores()
    }      
  });
});
```

Aca utilize un querySelectorAll que busca todos los botones con la clase 'memory-button' y dandole un value a cada boton

```
<button class="memory-button" value="rojo">Rojo</button>
```

Ya la logica de comprobar los colores te lo dejo

Comment: Hola , muchas Gracias!